# Using a workbook with VBA to open a saved workbook, modify that pre-existing workbook, save and close

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to be able to run a VBA command in an Excel workbook that will open a saved, existing workbook at a specified location (`Desktop\ThisBook.xlsx`).

After opening the `ThisBook.xlsx`, the command will take numerical values from specified cells in the VBA workbook (A1), add them to an existing cell in `ThisBook.xlsx` (something like `ThisBook.xlsx A1 = ThisBook.xlsx A1 + ActiveDocument A1`) and save them where the `ThisBook.xlsx data` was.

Finally, overwrite the previous save file for `ThisBook.xlsx` and overwrite the new data.

Comment: Try recording a macro and modifiying the resulting code.

Comment: You should review this post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579797/open-excel-file-for-reading-with-vba-without-display). It is VB, but not far off from what you need in VBA

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Macro1()
  ScreenUpdating = False
  Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\Parents\Desktop\ThisBook.xlsm"

  Windows("Book2.xlsm").Activate
  transfer = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value

  Windows("ThisBook.xlsm").Activate
  ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value + transfer

  ActiveWorkbook.Save
  ActiveWindow.Close
  ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```