# Excel file connected to access db is opening linked table source files

Tags: excel, ms-access

1. I have an Access database 'backend' with 2 linked tables, both linked to excel files 'Src1' & 'Src2'.
2. I have a query that joins a normal table and both linked tables in the database.
3. I have a table in another excel file 'Report' that is connected to the query in the db.

All works fine except for one strange issue. Sometimes when opening the 'Report' file, it automatically opens 'Src1' and 'Src2'. Why/how could this be happening?

Comment: Check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579797/open-excel-file-for-reading-with-vba-without-display) out

Comment: @PortlandRunner Thanks for the response but I'm not sure how that can help. the only reference to these 2 files is in the query in Access. Not anywhere in Excel...

Answer (score 0):

For Src1 and Src2, if you remove Src2 for example, what happens when you try to open Excel / Adcesss?  A quick way to check this would be to rename the Src1 or Src2 file.  Or, change your ODBC Connector..  Or?

You have to have a linked table, or Pass Through Query that is driving the mysterious connection.  Unless you have a UNC Path or mapped drive to a co-worker's machine.

HTH,

Kent

Comment: I tried renaming on of the files but 'Report' file bombed out on opening looking for a missing table/query. For info, all the files are in the same folder on a network drive and the problem is intermittent.