# Copying an Offset-Cell from a different File

Tags: vba, excel

I want to copy an offset cell which was first counted down in a list.

I am counting down, until the end +1, on the right side and then an offset from there to the DOWN,LEFT cell. And that number in the cell I want to copy into another file

Here is the code that does not work.
I know I use quite a lot of select and selection, which is probably the reason why it is not working.

```
Workbooks("Purchase Order Details for FY 2015.xlsx").Activate
         Worksheets("2015").Select
Range("B333").Select
        Selection.Copy
         Windows("Technology Purchase Order Template V4.xlsm").Activate
         Sheets("PO Authorization").Select
         Range("B5").Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get your error?

Comment: I did not say, that I got an error......It just doesn't do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Window` with `Workbooks`:

```
 Workbooks("Technology Purchase Order Template V4.xlsm").Activate
```

and maybe `Sheets` with `Worksheets`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
     Workbooks.open("Technology Purchase Order Template V4.xlsm").Activate
```

instead of

```
     Windows("Technology Purchase Order Template V4.xlsm").Activate
```

If you want to hide the opening/closing process, check out this answer:
[Open Excel file for reading with VBA without display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579797/open-excel-file-for-reading-with-vba-without-display)

Answer (score 0):

Sry that wasn't the Programm...Here is what I meant:

```
         Workbooks.Open("Purchase Order Details for FY 2015.xlsx").Activate
         Worksheets("2015").Select

         Selection = Worksheets("2015").Cells(Worksheets("2015").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
         Selection.Offset(1, -1).Copy

         Workbooks.Open("Technology Purchase Order Template V4.xlsm").Activate
         Worksheets("PO Authorization").Select
         Range("B5").Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste
         Sheets("SBB").Select
         Range("A2:W2").Select
         Selection.Copy

         Workbooks.Open("Purchase Order Details for FY 2015.xlsx").Activate
         Worksheets("2015").Select
         Selection = Cells(Worksheets("2015").Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row + 1
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Can somebody fix this please....you can see that I want to copy an offset cell into a file and from that file a range of cells into the bottom of a list with this Count(xlUp or xlDown) Function.

I hope somebody can solve this!

Erik

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Correct Code!

There are also some more functions in there so don't wonder.

```
Sub All_to_PDF_File()
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim sFile As String, sPath As String
    Dim wBook As Workbook
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

      On Error Resume Next
      Set wBook = Workbooks("Purchase Order Details for FY 2015.xlsx")

      If wBook Is Nothing Then 'Not open

      MsgBox "Please Open 'Purchase Order Details for FY 2015.xlsx' before running this macro!!"

      Set wBook = Nothing

      On Error GoTo 0

      Else 'It is open

         Workbooks("Purchase Order Details for FY 2015.xlsx").Activate
         Worksheets("2015").Select

         With ActiveSheet
            y = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
         End With

         Range("B" & y + 1).Select
         Selection.Copy

         Workbooks("Technology Purchase Order Template V4.xlsm").Activate
         Worksheets("PO Authorization").Select
         Range("B5").Select
         ActiveSheet.Paste

         Workbooks("Technology Purchase Order Template V4.xlsm").Activate
         Worksheets("SBB").Select
         Range("A2:W2").Select
         Selection.Copy

         Workbooks("Purchase Order Details for FY 2015.xlsx").Activate
         Worksheets("2015").Select

         With ActiveSheet
            x = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
         End With

         Range("C" & x + 1).Select
         Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


         Workbooks("Technology Purchase Order Template V4.xlsm").Activate
         Worksheets("PO Authorization").Select



    'Call the function with the correct arguments
    Filename = RDB_Create_PDF(ActiveWorkbook, "", True, True)

    'For a fixed file name and overwrite it each time you run the macro use
    'RDB_Create_PDF(ActiveWorkbook, "C:\Users\Ron\Test\YourPdfFile.pdf", True, True)

    If Filename <> "" Then
        'Ok, you find the PDF where you saved it
        'You can call the mail macro here if you want
    Else
        MsgBox "Not possible to create the PDF, possible reasons:" & vbNewLine & _
               "Microsoft Add-in is not installed" & vbNewLine & _
               "You Canceled the GetSaveAsFilename dialog" & vbNewLine & _
               "The path to Save the file in arg 2 is not correct" & vbNewLine & _
               "You didn't want to overwrite the existing PDF if it exist"
    End If
    End If


End Sub
```