# Make window open in background

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have 3 input boxes that when a document is selected it opens the document and fills in a select box. With `Excel 2013` these windows are opened in front of the document and have to be minimized in order to select the next one. Is there a way to have it automatically open documents in the background?

```
Workbooks.Open (file_path)
If Application.Version >= 15# Then
    ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMinimized
End If
```

This what I currently have, however I would rather it open in the background in the first place over having to minimize it. I have tried to turn off screen updating for the part, however that did not work.

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Workbooks.Open (file_path)
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Does `Application.ScreenUpdating` affect `WorkBooks.open` in `Excel 2013`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579797/open-excel-file-for-reading-with-vba-without-display

Comment: The form I'm using is Excel, so there will be multiple Excel windows up at the same time once the user chooses the first document

Comment: There are lot f suggestions mentioned in that link. Did you go through all and didn't like even a single suggestion :)?

Comment: Yes, thats where I went first, but the Issue is a excel 2013 issue and that was using 2007. My code works fine on 2007 but now that workbooks open in a new instance of excel as opposed to the same one they appear in front of the current users window.

Comment: Use `CreateObject` and open them in a separate instance (Hide that instance)

Answer (score 0):

Application.ScreenUpdating will not work with excel 2013.

You may try creating function:

```
Sub myScreenUpdate(screenUpdateRequest As Boolean, previousScreenUpdate As Boolean)
    If screenUpdateRequest Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = previousScreenUpdate
    Else
        previousScreenUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    End If
End Sub
```

call req:

1. Call myScreenUpdate(False, previousScreenUpdate)
2. Call myScreenUpdate(True, previousScreenUpdate)

   ```
   Dim previousScreenUpdate as boolean
   Call myScreenUpdate(False, previousScreenUpdate) 'to get the current setting into previousScreenUpdate
   Call myScreenUpdate(True, false)  'to set updating to false
   'do your heavy code here and when finished:
   Call myScreenUpdate(True, previousScreenUpdate)
   ```