# button to open another excel workbook minimized

Tags: excel, vba

i am using a userform with commandbox whose list is populating from another workbook. i have tried several ways to get the list populated without opening the other workbook but its way too complicated.
so i thought adding a button to the current workbook which would open the list source workbook in a minimized state could help.

i am using this code on the button click.

```
Sub Open_PriceList()
Workbooks.Open Filename:="F:\Document\Pricing\Price List.xlsx"
End Sub
```

is there anyway i could open the file in minimized state?

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579797/open-excel-file-for-reading-with-vba-without-display)

Comment: great idea @ScottCraner. OP, beware of early-binding in the answer to that post. I didn't see it notified in the answer (or anywhere).

Comment: I do not want to close the file. Just want to minimize it. if i close the file then the list would not populate anymore

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Sub Open_PriceList()
Workbooks.Open Filename:="F:\Document\Pricing\Price List.xlsx"
ActiveWindow.Visible = False
End Sub
```