# VBScript - Prevent Users from Unhide a hidden worksheet

Tags: excel, vbscript

I'am looking for a VBScript solution.

I can protect a worksheet:

ActiveSheet.Protect "password"

I can hide a worksheet:

ActiveSheet.Visible = False

But the user still can unhide the worksheet in Excel without a password.
Any solution for that?
Thanks

Comment: you gotta protect Your workbook

Comment: Only the sheet - the user must see the workbook without password. But i want see 1 worksheet, password protected.

Comment: The sheet will be possible to fetch unless you protect your workbook after you hide it. If you protect the sheet alone that will only halter changes in that.

Comment: i know, thats why i'am asking^^

Comment: Well then xlSheetVeryHidden would be the solution

Comment: Thats what smartobelix wrote but not a solution :(

Comment: If you right click to open sheets it won't show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide without possibility of unhiding from Excel UI:

`ActiveSheet.Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden`

Probably in VBScript it will be `ActiveSheet.Visible = 2`

EDIT:
After added clarification in comment:

I think the only way to achieve it will be to add on `Activate` event code to hide it always and protect VBA project by password. Something like below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    ActiveSheet.Visible = xlVeryHidden
End Sub
```

Then you can add Sub or Function to unhide this sheet with hard-coded password (password will be passed as argument and verified against hard-coded string). In this Sub you can set some global variable to bypass `Activate` logic.

Then unhiding from VBA Immediate window will also not work. In `BeforeSave` event you can hide this sheet to have it always hidden for other users.

Not sure if this fullfils your needs but I think it will be hard to achieve more.

Comment: Sounds good and grey out the menu to unhide the sheet, yes.

The problem is, i want to unhide it, but only by password. Sometimes i have to see the sheet values.
(Sorry i forgot that in my post)

Comment: the other problem is, i can ALT+F11 and set the visibility to 0 without a password :(

Comment: One more solution to hide this sensitive data could be to store them in separate workbook (fully password protected) and open them in background instance of Excel - like described here: [Open Excel file for reading with VBA without display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579797/open-excel-file-for-reading-with-vba-without-display)

Comment: Ok, i think it is not possible in VBS.
I have an excel file and vbs code on the first worksheet (need it for UFT/QTP test cases).
The user get all test results in all the other worksheets. I will hide the code for users and password protect it.
I will take the first solution from smartobelix, hope the users doesn't know Alt+F11^^
Thanks a lot guys ...