# Why does it say RuntimeError9 When Hiding an ActiveWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba

As the title says, my aim was to Open another workbook when opening one, which works perfectly fine.

Imagine now that the second workbook has to be opened for calculations on the first one, but I don't want to see the second one at all.

I accomplished that task with the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Workbooks.Open "E:\excelweeks\cw 38.xls"
On Error Resume Next
ActiveWorkbook.Windows("cw 38.xls").Visible = False

End Sub
```

It's pretty simple, but gives me

> Runtime error "9"

when running it, which I kind of understand but 1. it works nonetheless 2. can't seem to fix it, so I decided to just ignore the error, but I'm still curious.

Glad for any answer :)

Comment: Try to erase `ActiveWorkbook.` and leave just `Windows("cw 38.xls").Visible = False`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579797/open-excel-file-for-reading-with-vba-without-display

Comment: @Teamothy If I do that, it doesn't hide at all