# application.screenupdating=false when creating new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that looks something like this:

```
 sub my_code()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 

    'do lots of my things on my active workbook

    'then I create a new workbook and do stuff on that
    'looks like this:

    filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    fileName = Format(Date, "YYYY-MM-DD") & ".xlsx"    
    fileFullPath = filePath & fileName     
    Set newBook = Workbooks.Add
    newBook.SaveAs fileFullPath
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary").Copy Before:=Workbooks(fileName).Sheets(1)
    newBook.Sheets("Summary").UsedRange.Copy

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

So as you can see I am trying to get rid of the flashing when the macro runs. The flashing does not occur when I am doing work on my active workbook, but as soon as I start doing work on the new workbook, the flashing starts again. Why is this occurring, how do I stop it?

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: like trying to open a workbook minimized or hidden

Comment: using excel 2016

Comment: @Forward Ed ???

Comment: Just trying to summarize what I think you are after in a different set if words.

Comment: If you dont need the sheets to calculate during the execution of your macro, you can also turn automatic calculations off.

Comment: @a12345 Does this answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579797/open-excel-file-for-reading-with-vba-without-display) work for you?

Comment: No it's not the same problem as me