Importing a value from closed workbook
I'm sorry in advance, I just don't know how to word my problem well.
I work with information of surveyed trees that is stored in excel. I have had some success using VBA macros to  import the data from excel into a word template.
The supplied data has the latin species name of the trees, but not the common. I am making a list of all the species and their common names in another workbook.
Is there a way for my macro to search for the species value in my "list" workbook, return the corresponding common name so it can be pasted to a bookmark in a Word template, preferably without having to open the "list" workbook? Sometimes the data can be substantial
Sorry in advance if I'm wasting anyone's time with this question.
My VBA experience is very limited, constantly getting syntax errors. I just don't know how to approach this problem.
Any help would would be greatly appreciated.
Here is an example of what I'm working with:
Workbook running macro
"List" book

The only way to access data from Excel without "opening" the file is by using ADODB and issue a query, however, that's definitively not for beginners. But you can open a workbook without displaying it, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579797/open-excel-file-for-reading-with-vba-without-display

ExecuteExcel4Macro to get value from closed workbook

An approach could be to use the following function
Option Explicit

Function getValueFromFile(path As String, file As String, sheet As String, rowNo As Long, colNo As Long) As String
        
    Dim arg As String
    arg = "'" & path & "[" & file & "]" & sheet & "'!R" & rowNo & "C" & colNo

    'Run XL4-Macro
    getValueFromFile = ExecuteExcel4Macro(arg)
    
End Function

Here how you can use it. This example will retrieve the value of cell B2 in Sheet1.
Sub Main()
    Dim res As String
    res = getValueFromFile("D:\TMP\", "xlFile.xlsx", "Sheet1", 2, 2)
End Sub

Here you find a version using ADODB

I did exactly that for my agreement templates. Check Greg Maxey's website for more info on ADODB (that's where I read about it).
First make sure that data in your excel workbook is properly organized: row 1 must be a header as it won't be imported (alternatively, you can switch that setting off by changing the corresponding argument of the function below).
Put this code in a module, it pulls all data from a chosen sheet into an array (array must be declared as Variant, I made it a public variable):
Option Explicit

Public arrData As Variant 'all designated signers' names and their power of attorneys (that's where your tree names will end up after importing)
Public arrData_secondary As Variant 'array of unique singers' names for filtering, you don't really need it 

Function ExcelDataToArray(strWorkbook As String, _
    Optional strRange As String, _
    Optional bIsSheet As Boolean = True, _
    Optional bHeaderRow As Boolean = True) As Variant
       
    'задаем переменные
    Dim oRS As Object
    Dim oConn As Object
    Dim lngRows As Long
    Dim strHeaderYES_NO As String
    
        strHeaderYES_NO = "YES" 'assume that worbook has headers
        If Not bHeaderRow Then strHeaderYES_NO = "NO" 'you can choose "no headers" setting
        
        If bIsSheet Then strRange = strRange & "$]" Else strRange = strRange & "]" 'data source is the whole sheet by default
        
        Set oConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
        oConn.Open ConnectionString:="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & strWorkbook & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=" & strHeaderYES_NO & """;"  'change OLEDB version to 4.0 and excel version to 8.0 if it doesn't work
        Set oRS = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
        oRS.Open "SELECT * FROM [" & strRange, oConn, 2, 1 'open excel file and extract data form preset sheet strating from row 2
        With oRS
            .MoveLast
            lngRows = .RecordCount
            .MoveFirst
        End With
        ExcelDataToArray = oRS.GetRows(lngRows)
        
lbl_exit:
        If oRS.State = 1 Then oRS.Close
        Set oRS = Nothing
        If oConn.State = 1 Then oConn.Close
        Set oConn = Nothing
        
        Exit Function
End Function

The code above is a function that fills an array. You can use it like this:
Sub get_tree_name()

Dim aDoc as Document
set aDoc = ActiveDocument

Dim strWorkbook as String 'declare string variable for wokbookname
Dim criterium as string 'declare string variable for filtering

Dim i as Long

strWorkbook = "full path to your workbook, including file name and extension" 'Workbook name from which data will be extracted

arrData = ExcelDataToArray(strWorkbook, "put name of the sheet from which you want to extract data") 'extracting data form the chosen sheet

'looking for "criterium" value in arrData 
criterium = "your criterium" 'you can even set it via Userform content controls
                    
For i = 0 To UBound(arrData, 2) Step 1 'i from 0 to the number of rows in "arrData" array 
'rows / columns in any array a numbered form 0, so first row/column is 0, second is 1 etc.
                        
   If InStr(1, arrData(1, i), criterium, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then 'looping through all rows in the SECOND column
                            
        aDoc.SelectControlsbyTitle("name of content control in the document").Item(1).Range.Text = arrData(2, i) 'filling content control in your document with value from row i in the THIRD column (if the condition is met)

   End If

Next i
    
End Sub

Once you'll have created an array, you need to find the right value in it with Instr() function as I showed in get_tree_name macro. If the condition is met, you can put data in content control somewhere in your document.
By the way, it's better to use content controls instead of bookmarks if you want to put some data in your document. Bookmarks are deleted every time you change their text with VBA (you can fix it, but that's another story).

There are actually several ways you could get the data into Word without opening the workbook in Excel, but underneath, they all use ADODB/OLEDB/ODBC as has been mentioned.
This particular approach uses InsertDatabase, which normally insert a table of data except when it's only inserting a single row and column. Although even then Word inserts the paragraph mark it would normally insert at the beginning of a table. It's just that using InsertDatabase (or even a DATABASE field) means that you don't actually have to provide an Excel Connection string, as Word does all that "under the hood"
If you have selected the Latin ('Species') name and you want to insert the common name into a bookmarked location, you can use code like this:
Sub insertCommonName(rng As Word.Range, Species As String, XLWBFullName As String, XLAreaName As String, AreaIsSheet As Boolean, SpeciesColumnName As String, CommonNameColumnName As String)

' If there is more than one row with the given species name,
' this should pick the first
On Error GoTo problem

' The driver/provider needs a "$" at the end of sheet names, but that
' isn't needed for other named areas.
Dim AreaName As String
If AreaIsSheet And Right(XLAreaName, 1) <> "$" Then
  AreaName = XLAreaName & "$"
Else
  AreaName = XLAreaName
End If

rng.Text = ""
rng.Collapse WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart
rng.InsertDatabase _
  SQLStatement:=" SELECT [" & CommonNameColumnName & "]" & _
                " FROM [" & AreaName & "]" & _
                " WHERE UCase([" & SpeciesColumnName & "]) = '" & UCase(Species) & "'", _
  DataSource:=XLWBFullName, _
  From:=1, _
  To:=1, _
  IncludeFields:=False
rng.Delete
Exit Sub

problem:
MsgBox "Could not find the requested Species in the list."
Err.Clear
End Sub

Sub testInsertCommonName()
' Put the full pathname of your XL "List" workbook in here
Const XLWB As String = "C:\myxldbs\speciescommonnames.xlsx"
Const SheetName As String = "Sheet1"
Const SpeciesColumnName As String = "Species"
Const CommonNameColumnName As String = "Common name"

' Get the species name. Here, I'm assuming it's in the Word Selection
' and may have some additional space at either end. (NB, Trim() does not trim
' all types of white space, e.g. it doesn't remove tab characters)
' You may want to do more tests.

Dim s As String
s = Trim(Selection.Text)

' Get the range where you want to put the result.
 ' Here, we 're using a bookmark name to get the range

If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("cn") Then
  Dim r As Word.Range
  Set r = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("cn").Range
  Call insertCommonName(r, s, XLWB, SheetName, True, SpeciesColumnName, CommonNameColumnName)
   Set r = Nothing
Else
  MsgBox "Could not find the bookmark 'cn'"
End If
End Sub

